# Difference between Producer and Consumer count in tibco admin

Tags: tibco, tibco-ems

I have one doubt regarding difference between producer count and consumer count in TIBCO EMS which we see in TIBCO Admin --> all services instances --> ems now on selecting the specific ems server --> connections.

please can anybody help me in understanding both the terminologies.
please let me know if anything left from my side .

[image: Below is the screenshot where we get producer and consumer count in TIBCO Administrator]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The count of the producers and consumer do not correlate to each other in any way.

The producer count is the amount of producers instantiated in your Java code. So each producer can send messages to the connected queue.

The consumer count is the amount of consumers instantiated in your Java code. So each consumer can receive messages from the connected queue.

So it is possible to have a client which simultaneously sends and receives messages, but this is purely based on your implementation.

Comment: Thanks jens I got it . Why I have asked this question is actually in TIBCO EMS guide we have command for consumer i.e. Show Consumer but no any command for producer .